# GCP Cloud Functions Gen 2 - Cannot call through NodeJs or gcloud

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I created a gen 2 cloud function on my project "project-x" and used everything default, with permission `Allow unauthenticated`:

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

functions.http('helloHttp', (req, res) => {
 res.send(`Hello ${req.query.name || req.body.name || 'World'}!`);
});
```

This generated a URL for this function, e.g. `https://my-function-bvskvwq11c-uc.a.run.app`, which when I call unauthenticated (or visit on the browser) it works. I see the response.

Now here's the problem...

---

**A.** Using the npm package [@google-cloud/functions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/functions) I tried to call this endpoint with the following:

```
await functionsClient.callFunction({
    name: 'my-function',
})
```

This gives me a weird error of the format:

```
7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud Functions API has not been used in project ********* before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/overview?project=********* then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

I say this is a weird error, cause the project ID provided in this error is not the ID of my project on GCP and when I visit the link provided it says I do not have permissions to view this project.

Then I tried to list my functions by doing the following, but I get back an empty list.

```
const [functions] = await functionsClient.listFunctions({
    parent: `projects/project-x/locations/us-central1`,
});
// functions = [];
```

---

**B.** I thought to try [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) this time, so first I listed all functions for my project:

```
gcloud functions list
```

This actually returned the correct function:

```
NAME           STATE   TRIGGER       REGION       ENVIRONMENT
my-function    ACTIVE  HTTP Trigger  us-central1  2nd gen
```

I'm like cool! Let's try to call it now. So I run:

```
gcloud functions call my-function
```

And I get the following back:

```
ResponseError: status=[404], code=[Ok], message=[Function my-function in region us-central1 in project project-x does not exist]
```

---

Can someone please shed some light in all of these? Listing through the npm package yields different results than the gcloud command and neither of them are able to call the function. One gives 404 and the other one permission denied. What would be the best approach?

Comment: Update: Running `gcloud functions call my-function --gen2` did work. So it seems you have to specify the gen of the function with the `--gen2` option. Looking further into the npm package issue now...

Comment: Update #2: From the [Rate Limits](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#rate_limits) page: `The CALL API only applies to Cloud Functions (1st gen). Please keep in mind that this API is meant for testing via Cloud Console or gcloud functions call CLI, and it cannot handle heavy traffic`. So it seems the npm package should not be used... I think this should be mentioned first thing on their repo. Looking for alternatives now and into the [google-auth-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library) package.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question and summarizing.

---

To call a gen2 function from the gcloud command, use the `--gen2` option, as stated on the [gcloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/call):

```
gcloud functions call my-function --gen2
```

---

To call gen2 functions from NodeJs, do not use the `@google-cloud/functions` package. As stated in Google's [Rate Limits](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#rate_limits) documentation:

> The CALL API only applies to Cloud Functions (1st gen)... Please keep in mind that this API is meant for testing via Cloud Console or gcloud functions call CLI, and it cannot handle heavy traffic.

Instead, use the [google-auth-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library) package, where they also have an [example on how to call a function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library#user-content-working-with-id-tokens):

```
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');

async function main() {
  const url = 'https://cloud-run-1234-uc.a.run.app';
  const auth = new GoogleAuth();
  const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(url);
  const res = await client.request({url});
  console.log(res.data);
}
```